# Ant installation on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to install apache ant on windows server 2008.I Setup the enviroment vars as:

`ANT_HOME=C:\ant
JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%;C:\ant\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

And when I running ant -version it keeps bringing me this massage:
ant_home is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. please set ant_home.

Ant works perfectly on my local machine (win10), I just copied the setting same as it on my local machine and it is doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but I think that `PATH=%JAVA_HOME%;...` ought to be `PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...`. The `JAVA_HOME` variable should be the Java installation root,  not the installation's bin directory.

Comment: Hi thanks for you feedback but the java_home var pointing as it should be